To find the minimum value of a from the polynomial $f(x)=ax^2 - bx + c $
Let the polynomial $f(x)=ax^2–bx+c$ (where $a$, $b$ & $c$ are positive integers). If $f(p)=f(q)=0$, where $0<p<q<1$ , then find the minimum possible value of $a$???
The vertex is −$(\frac{−b}{2a})=(\frac{b}{2a})>0$
and lies between 0 & 1
my approach

by $af(0)>0$ we get $a(c)>0$ and $a(a-b+c)>0$
another condition $0<(\frac{b}{2a})<1$
another condition $D>0$

but i cant find $a$ using this :(

Welcome to MSE. Because $a,b,c$ are positive, the parabola will have either two (possibly repeated) positive roots or two (again, possibly repeated) negative roots. However, it seems like there is additional information missing, because we can make $a$ as arbitrarily close to zero as we like and still find a parabola that satisfies these conditions. Are you able to elaborate and perhaps say where the question originated?

@RedFive $a$ has to be an integer...

@RedFive See my answer.  Note that the problem does state that $~a,b,c~$ are positive integers.

Yes, now I see. The integer part of the condition is deceptive but key. Good answer.


Let the polynomial $f(x)=ax^2–bx+c$ (where $a$, $b$ & $c$ are positive integers). If $f(p)=f(q)=0$, where $0<p<q<1$ , then find the minimum possible value of $a$?

$$p = \frac{1}{2a} \left[ ~b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} ~\right], 
~~q = \frac{1}{2a} \left[ ~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} ~\right].$$
So,
$$b > \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}, ~~~b^2 > 4ac, ~~~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} < 2a. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, note that you can't have $~b^2 - 4ac = 0,~$ since this would violate the constraint that $~p < q.$
Since $~a,b,c \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~$ this implies that
$$b^2 - 4ac \geq 1 \implies \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \geq 1.$$
This implies that $~ b > 1.~$
Therefore
$$b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} > 2 \implies a > 1.$$
So, the next step is to explore whether you can have $~a = 2.~$
Then, you have that
$$p = \frac{1}{4} \left[ ~b - \sqrt{b^2 - 8c} ~\right], 
~~q = \frac{1}{4} \left[ ~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 8c} ~\right].$$
Since $~c~$ is a positive integer, you must have that $~c \geq 1,~$ and $~b \geq 3.~$  Then, the minimum possible value of $~\displaystyle \sqrt{b^2 - 8c}~$ is $~1.~$
This implies that the minimum possible value of 
$~\displaystyle b + \sqrt{b^2 - 8c}~$ is $~4.~$
With $~a~$ assumed to equal $~2,~$ this violates the constraint that $~q < 1.~$
Therefore, you must have $~a \geq 3.~$
So, the next step is to explore if $~a = 3~$ is viable.
Then, you have that
$$p = \frac{1}{6} \left[ ~b - \sqrt{b^2 - 12c} ~\right], 
~~q = \frac{1}{6} \left[ ~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 12c} ~\right].$$
Then, if $~b = 4,~$ you have that $~c = 1,~$ so $~\sqrt{b^2 - 12c} = 2.~$  This also leads to $~q = 1.$
Further, $~b \geq 5~$ is also no good, since $~\displaystyle \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \geq 1.$
So, the next step is to explore if $~a = 4~$ is viable.
Then,
$$p = \frac{1}{8} \left[ ~b - \sqrt{b^2 - 16c} ~\right], 
~~q = \frac{1}{8} \left[ ~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 16c} ~\right].$$
Here, $~b = 6~$ leads to $~\displaystyle \sqrt{b^2 - 16c} \geq 2,~$ which is no good.
Also, $~b = 5~$ leads to $~c = 1,~$ which is also no good.
Further, clearly, you can't have $~b > 6,~$ or $~b < 5.$
Therefore $~a = 4~$ is not viable.
Therefore, the problem reduces to proving that $~a = 5~$ is viable.
Then,
$$p = \frac{1}{10} \left[ ~b - \sqrt{b^2 - 20c} ~\right], 
~~q = \frac{1}{10} \left[ ~b + \sqrt{b^2 - 20c} ~\right].$$
Here, you can have (for example), $~b = 5, c = 1,~$ which works.
So, the minimum value of $~a~$ is $~5.$
